# C++ Builder 2010 How to switch to FASTMM

Tags: c++builder, fastmm

I have some projects which were done in c++ builder 2009 and they need borlandmm.dll to run. I have read that c++ Builder 2010 by default use Fastmm, but it doesn't seems to be the case in my projects. They still need borlandmm.dll

So how can I switch my projects to use Fastmm ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create empty project - it should not require borlandmm.dll.

You've probably used some unit, which requires borlandmm.dll.